# React Router v4 show current route component until async route resolve

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-loadable

I am using `react-router v4` along side `react-loadable` to async load matched routes.

```js
<LayoutWrapper>
  <Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={props =>
      currentUser ? (
        <AsycnExamplePage {...props} currentUser={currentUser} />
      ) : (
        <AsycnExamplePage />
      )}
  />
  <Route
    exact
    path="/saved"
    render={props => <AsycnExamplePage {...props} currentUser={currentUser} />}
  />
  <Route
    exact
    path="/settings"
    render={props => (
      <AsycnExamplePage {...props} currentUser={currentUser} />
    )}
  />
</LayoutWrapper>
```

- `AsycnExamplePage` is a component wrapped with `Loadable` from `react-loadable`, e.g:

```js
Loadable({
  loader: () => import("./index"),
  loading: props => {
    if (props.isLoading) {
      NProgress.start();
    }
    return null;
  },
});
```

Currently, as I route to a different page, `react-router` will instantly match the route before the async route is resolve. Thereby showing the `LoadingComponent` from `react-loadable`.

How can I make it so that `react-router` will only render the async component **after** the async component is resolved?

PS: I'm trying to create a page load effect similar to [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/).

Comment: I would guess that this is a feature/issue with Loadable. There may be a config option to turn this off. Or set the loading prop to null.